# MSAccess Query: Generate two fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a `MS Access` view generating this result:

```
+-------+------------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
|  Id   |    Date    | Kind  | Initial | Final  | Total |
+-------+------------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
| 334AB | 01/04/2017 | Red   |  199725 | 199789 |    64 |
| 334AB | 01/04/2017 | Green |  199789 | 199799 |    10 |
| 107AE | 01/04/2017 | Red   |   73978 |  74074 |    96 |
| 107AE | 02/04/2017 | Green |   74074 |  74248 |   174 |
+-------+------------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Generated with:

```
Group by ID, Date and Kind
Initial: Min(startKm)
Final: Max(endKm)
Total: Sum(Distance)
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT street.Id, street.Date, IIf(IsNull([agev]), Kind, Min(street.Initial) AS Iniziali, Max(street.Final) AS Finali, Sum(street.Distance) AS Total
FROM street
GROUP BY street.Id, street.Date, Kind
ORDER BY street.Date;
```

What I need is this result:

```
+-------+------------+---------+--------+----------+------------+-------+
|  Id   |    Date    | Initial | Final  | TotalRed | TotalGreen | Total |
+-------+------------+---------+--------+----------+------------+-------+
| 334AB | 01/04/2017 |  199725 | 199799 |       64 |         10 |    74 |
| 107AE | 01/04/2017 |   73978 |  74074 |       96 |          0 |    96 |
| 107AE | 02/04/2017 |   74074 |  74248 |        0 |        174 |   174 |
+-------+------------+---------+--------+----------+------------+-------+
```

Where Initial is the lowest "initial" km in that day by that id
and Final is the higher "Final" km in that day by that id

What do you suggest?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should work out like this:

```
    SELECT street.Id
          ,street.Date
          ,Min(street.Initial) AS Iniziali
          ,Max(street.Final) AS Finali
          ,SUM(IIF(street.Kind = 'Red',street.Distance,0)) AS TotalRed
          ,SUM(IIF(street.Kind = 'Green',street.Distance,0)) AS TotalGreen
          ,Sum(street.Distance) AS Total 
      FROM street 
  GROUP BY street.Id
          ,street.Date
  ORDER BY street.Date;
```